# RxJava: Split Rx Flowable into multiple streams

Tags: java, stream, rx-java

I would like to perform some operations on stream, and then split stream into two streams, and then process them separately.

Example to show problem:

```
Flowable<SuccessfulObject> stream = Flowable.fromArray(
        new SuccessfulObject(true, 0),
        new SuccessfulObject(false, 1),
        new SuccessfulObject(true, 2));

stream = stream.doOnEach(System.out::println);

Flowable<SuccessfulObject> successful = stream.filter(SuccessfulObject::isSuccess);
Flowable<SuccessfulObject> failed = stream.filter(SuccessfulObject::isFail);

successful.doOnEach(successfulObject -> {/*handle success*/}).subscribe();
failed.doOnEach(successfulObject -> {/*handle fail*/}).subscribe();
```

Class:

```
class SuccessfulObject {
    private boolean success;
    private int id;

    public SuccessfulObject(boolean success, int id) {
        this.success = success;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
    public boolean isFail() {
        return !success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SuccessfulObject{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

But this code prints all elements twice whereas I would like to perform all operations before splitting only once.
Output:

> OnNextNotification[SuccessfulObject{id=0}]
>   OnNextNotification[SuccessfulObject{id=1}]
>   OnNextNotification[SuccessfulObject{id=2}] 
> OnCompleteNotification
>   OnNextNotification[SuccessfulObject{id=0}]
>   OnNextNotification[SuccessfulObject{id=1}]
>   OnNextNotification[SuccessfulObject{id=2}] 
> OnCompleteNotification

How can I process the stream to receive this behaviour?

Comment: Do you want to merge the result of handling back together to one stream (fork-join-behaviour?)

Comment: No, just split streams and perform all operations separately.

Comment: Well, then use the solution from @akarnokd. As a side-node: do not use mutable objects in rx-pipeline. Also isFail is not necessary, because isSuccess implies on fals, that it failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `publish` to share a subscription to the source:

```
Flowable<Integer> source = Flowable.range(1, 5);

ConnectableFlowable<Integer> cf = source.publish();

cf.filter(v -> v % 2 == 0).subscribe(v -> System.out.println("Even: " + v));

cf.filter(v -> v % 2 != 0).subscribe(v -> System.out.println("Odd: " + v));

cf.connect();
```